# Factor variable forced to logical when csv imported in R

Tags: r, read.csv

I want to import a csv file but a variable is not correctly read.

Here is an extract of the file when I read it with Windows notepad :

```
id,claim,automatic_generation
2839,f,f
2840,f,f
2841,t,f
2842,t,t
```

I've imported the csv file with this function :

```
data <- read.csv(file="ventes.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",")
```

and the column claim is not correctly read : it is always TRUE regardless the value of the variable.

Here is what I see if I do str(data)

```
'data.frame':   4 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ id                         : int  2839 2840 2841 2842
 $ claim                      : logi  TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
 $ automatic_generation       : Factor w/ 2 levels "f","t": 1 1 1 0
```

Ideally, I would like to have two logical variables : TRUE for "t" and FALSE for "f"

Comment: R can't guess that t and f are to be imported as logical. As they are text, they are interpreted as strings and then coerced to factors. This is the default fo read.csv.
You have to use the `colClasses` argument to define the class of each of your columns and recode t and f to TRUE or FALSE.

Comment: Thanks, It's done. Anyway I don't understand why for atomatic_generation  R defined the variable as factor and for claim it did as logical, even if both have the same possible values "f" and "t"

Answer (score 0):

Try using **T** or **F** in the source csv like this:

```
bash>$ cat data
#one,two,three
#1,2,T
#1,2,T
#2,3,F
#2,3,F
#3,4,T
```

```
d <- read.csv("./data", header=T, sep=",")
#   one two three
#1    1   2  TRUE
#2    1   2  TRUE
#3    2   3 FALSE
#4    2   3 FALSE
#5    3   4  TRUE
> d$three == F
# [1] FALSE FALSE TRUE TRUE FALSE
```

You can also force this behavior if you are unsure:

```
d <- read.csv("./dd", colClasses=c("numeric", "numeric", "logical"))
```